# how to use css variables in @font-face url

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

```css
:root {
  --icon-url: '//at.alicdn.com/t/font_126288_147h8m0m5se5ewmi';
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'iconfont';
  src: url(var(--icon-url)'.eot');
  src: url(var(--icon-url)'.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url(var(--icon-url)'.woff') format('woff'), url(var(--icon-url)'.ttf') format('truetype'), url(var(--icon-url)'.svg#iconfont') format('svg');
}
```

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './var(--icon-url' in 'Users/xxx/xxx'

Answer (score 7):

CSS variable not supported in src or src's url.

Comment: Confirmed as of today. I wasn't able to declare CSS variable in `:root` and utilize it in `@font-face` definition of an externally hosted CSS file.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The question is about @font-face, which cannot use css variables. Tried multiple variations of code before seeing this answer.

Answer (score 5):

if you want to specify a URL in a custom property, you need to write out the entire url() expression, and substitute that entire expression:

```
:root {
      --url: url("https://download.unsplash.com/photo-1420708392410-3c593b80d416");
}

body {
   background: var(--url);
}
```

Comment: different file suffixes define different variables？can variables be suffixed without the file?

Comment: @Jerome no they cannot

Answer (score 3):

Found this considerably after the fact, but you tagged this as `sass` in addition to `css`. In SASS, you CAN include this as a variable. You have to pass the variable with special syntax, though.

Instead of just `$url` you have to pass it like so: `#{$url}`. Then SASS will know to include the string directly.

Example:

```
/* Set variable in SASS (will not be CSS variable) */
$icon-url: '//at.alicdn.com/t/font_126288_147h8m0m5se5ewmi';

@font-face {
  font-family: 'iconfont';
  src: url('#{$icon-url}.eot');
  src: url('#{$icon-url}.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
       url('#{$icon-url}.woff') format('woff'), 
       url(var(--icon-url)'.ttf') format('truetype'), 
       url('#{$icon-url}.svg#iconfont') format('svg');
}
```

Mind you, at this point, you could just use woff2 and woff, so this may be less needed.

See https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_font-face_woff

Answer (score 0):

```css
:root {
  --icon-url: url('//at.alicdn.com/t/font_126288_147h8m0m5se5ewmi');
}
```